# Identifying & troubleshooting ceiling fan

Tags: ceiling-fan

I am currently troubleshooting a ceiling fan in my home. Attached are pictures, one with a sticker providing information on the ceiling fan type & the other of the fan itself. On the sticker it states "A.C. Ceiling Fan 120V 60Hz" and the "Series" is CF42-P. It also states Ruston(CF42RUS5BK). I did some preliminary research and I am finding very little information on this ceiling fan. The reason I'm reaching out: the fan is not operational and I am wondering if it needs a remote to make it operational (which I do not have).

[image]

[image]

Appreciate any advice, link to a manual or help!

Comment: Most remote fans I've worked with also have manual controls. Is there a wall switch? On the side of the canopy there appears to be a silver nodule that may have housed a pull chain at some point. It would be good to see if it runs at all before chasing the possibility of a remote.

Comment: it needs a remote to make it operational (which I do not have) - and prob can't get, for a 9yo fan. Take the fan down and make a light bulb work. Then put it back minus the controller. Or if it's only one switch leg wire, and there's no chains, and you want diff speeds and/or a light kit, then you need a new fan - or a 3-position fan switch on the wall, provided the fan itself is stuck in *high*. - (How much is a remote and how much is a new fan?) Verify incoming power, is step one and has nothing to do with the manual. - Us looking for a manual so that you can buy a thing is kinda off topic.

Comment: Take the escutcheon canopy off the top. If there's a black box with 20 wires coming out of it (the controller) shoved in there, then yes it 'needs' a remote. Or you could hardwire it, assuming it comes from a switch and not just a random live wire. - Maybe the controller has the numbers you need on it.

Comment: Thank you, HoneyDo and Mazura for your assistance. It is operational through a switch.